# VARCHAR column with numeric and non-numeric data to be filtered by numeric comparasion in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

DB: Oracle (But I'm looking for generic solution in ANSI SQL)

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.FIELD_KEY = B.FIELD_KEY
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (FIELD_VALUE) < 10
```

I've a table (TABLE1) which stores 'Value' and 'Frequency'. Now data in the `FIELD_VALUE` column can be numeric as well as non-numeric. The datatype of this column is `VARCHAR2`. I want to filter this table where Value < 10 (say).

I understand that 'Where TO_NUMBER(Value) < 10' won't work because Value column contains non numeric data as well.

But, I'm joining table `TABLE1` with table `TABLE2` Such that post join only numeric values are returned in the resultset in 'Value' column and then I'm applying 'Where TO_NUMBER(Value) < 10'on this already filtered resultset. I'm expecting that since the resultset is already filtered and contains only numeric data in the 'Value' column I should be able to filter the resultset further with 'Where TO_NUMBER(Value) < 10' caluse but that ain't happening due to the fact that Oracle optimizer changes the order of my where clause and join condition thus I'm getting 'ORA-01722: invalid number' error.

Solution that works for me is:

```
WITH BASE_QUERY
     AS (SELECT *
           FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.FIELD_KEY = B.FIELD_KEY)
SELECT *
  FROM    BASE_QUERY A
       INNER JOIN
          BASE_QUERY B
       ON A.VALUE = B.VALUE AND TO_NUMBER (FIELD_VALUE) < 10
```

But I've to do a self-join here which is costly and unnecessary. Plus I'm not sure if this solution will work always. I mean, if Oracle changes the execution plan and executes `TO_NUMBER (FIELD_VALUE) < 10` before joining the tables then the query might again fail with same `ORA-01722: invalid number ‘error.

Questions:

1. Is my solution guaranteed to work always?
2. Is my solution reasonable performance wise?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why store mixed data like that??? (Use reg_exp to find true numeric values.)

Answer (score 0):

> But I've to do a self-join here which is costly and unnecessary.

So don't do the join at all. All you need is the rows which have the `FIELD_VALUE` as only **DIGIT**. You want to ignore the **ALPHANUMERIC** values. So, filter out only the digits.

For example,

**TRANSLATE and REPLACE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'mix-'||LEVEL str FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10
  3  UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_char(LEVEL) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10
  5  )
  6  SELECT str FROM DATA
  7  WHERE REPLACE(translate(str, '0123456789',' '), ' ') IS NULL
  8  /

STR
--------------------------------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**REGEXP_LIKE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'mix-'||LEVEL str FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10
  3  UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_char(LEVEL) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10
  5  )
  6  SELECT str FROM DATA
  7  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^[[:digit:]]+')
  8  /

STR
--------------------------------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Personally, I would go with TRANSLATE and REPLACE, since REGEXP is still quite resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If  you can guarantee that content in `field_value` starting with a digit will be strictly numeric, you can employ a subquery that filters your table to leave only records that have numeric content in the `field_value` column:

```
select *
  from (
           select t1.*
             from table t1
            where t1.field_value >= '0'
              and t1.field_value <= chr(ascii('9')+1) -- ':'; invariant to charset and encoding
       ) t
 where to_number(t.field_value) < 10
     ;
```

I'd rather advise you to use one of Lalit Kumar B's solution which appear to be  more robust ( think of a relaxation of the 'infer numeric from initial digit' policy in the future ).